# Error 404 Help registration page

Tags: php, docker, xampp

Building a registration page, using docker and xampp and getting :

> Error 404
>
> The requested URL was not found on this server. The link on the referring page seems to be wrong or outdated.

I've had a look at every forum page related and gone through every Google search result and tutorial I can find and still no luck. After validating the PHP and digging through the compose file I'm now stuck.

My guess is I've made a mistake with my PHP or it is something to do with the Docker image porting that I've missed. I'm a beginner at all this.

Docker image used:

https://hub.docker.com/r/tomsik68/xampp/

```
docker run --name myXampp -p 41061:22 -p 41062:80 -d -v ~/my_web_pages:/www tomsik68/xampp
```

Form used:

```
   <div class="fieldset">
<form method="post" action="includes/test.php">
        <fieldset>
            <h2>Create Login</h2>
            <p><label for="Company_name">Company Name * </label><input type="text" id="company_name" name="company_name" /></p>
            <p><label for="pass">Password * </label><input type="password" id="pass" name="company_name"/></p>
              <!--<p><label for="pass2">Confirm Password * </label><input type="password" id="pass2" /></p>-->
          <p><label for="email">Email * </label><input type="email" id="email" name="email" /></p>
            <p><label for="telephone">Telephone </label><input type="text" id="telephone" name="telephone"/></p>
            <p class="required">* Required</p>
            <p><input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit-regestration" name="submit-regestration"/></p>
```

PHP page:

```
<?php

if (isset($post['submit'])) {
include_once 'db_connect.php';


$company_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,     $_POST['company_name']);
$pass= mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['pass']);
$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['email']);



if (empty($company_name) || empty($pass) || empty($email)) {
header("Location: ../test.php?signup=empty");
exit();

}else{

    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z]*$/", $company_name) ||        !preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z]*$/",$pass)){
    header("Location: ../test.php?invalid");
    exit();
} else {

if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
header("Location: ../test.php?invalidemail");
exit();
} else {

$sql = "SELECT * FROM company_reg WHERE        company_name='$company_name'";
$result= mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);

if($resultCheck >0){
    header("Location: ../test.php?User_taken");
    exit();
} else {

    $hashedPwd =Password_hash($Pass, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

    $sql = "INSERT INTO company_reg (company_name,pass,email) VALUES ('$company_name', '$hashedPwd','$email');";
mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
header("Location: ../mreg3.html");
}
}

}

}

} else {
header("Location: ../test.php");
exit();
}

 ?>
```

Comment: Does the form display, but when submitting you get 404? Or you never get form to display, it's 404 trying to even access? If the former, does the target (`includes/test.php`) in fact exist?

Comment: Note that `mysqli_real_escape_string` in not infallible in preventing SQL injection. I suggest you swap to bound parameters.

Comment: Regarding `-p 41061:22`, you don't need to SSH into a running container. Just use a shell instead: `docker exec -it container_name bash`.

Comment: I would suggest you start the container, shell into it, `cd` to what you think the docroot is, and see if your web app files are there. My guess is the files are in the wrong location, or your web server docroot config is wrongly set.

Comment: Thanks Patrick, test was in the correct position. Halfer it was the config in the end, took me a while to figure out. Thanks for the help